# Error when running discord bot piece of code

Tags: discord.js

So when running te following piece of code:

```
            case 'greeting':
            if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Foloseste "//greeting')
            else
            canal = args[1]
            message.channel.send("Done")
            } else {
                message.channel.send("Nu esti administrator")
            }

            break;
```

I get the following error

```
                if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
                ^

ReferenceError: member is not defined
```

So how do I define member? Also tell me if there is something wrong with the code. I am trying to make it so that users with the administrator permission to be able to change the value of "canal". Thanks for your patience reading this!

Comment: Use `message.member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like jakye said, you are looking for `message.member`, if you want to store it inside a variable/define it just use the normal variable syntax:

```js
const member = message.member;
```